# IC with SDCard and LVDS interfaces for video playback, what are they called?

Tags: video

I am looking to build a board that can connect to an LVDS LCD screen and play back videos from an SD card when triggered via a serial port command, or I2C, or similar. I have seen cards like that on the market, but can't find any ICs with that functionality. What would it be called?

Comment: A job well suited to an FPGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chips you seek are called Digital Media Processors.